# Create File at user defined path

Tags: java, file, file-io

I am creating a file in java using

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(FileName));          
StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
sb.append("\n");
sb.append("work");
out.write(sb.toString());
out.close();
```

But this file is getting created inside the bin folder of my server.I would like to create this file inside a user-defined folder.

How can it be achieved.

Comment: are you running from an IDE (like eclipse) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to create this file inside a user-defined folder.

The simplest approach is to specify a fully qualified path name. You could select that as a `File` and build a new `File` relative to it:

```
File directory = new File("/home/jon/somewhere");
File fullPath = new File(directory, fileName);
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
    new OutputStreamWriter(
        (new FileOutputStream(fullPath), charSet));
try {
    writer.write("\n");
    writer.write("work");
} finally {
    writer.close();
}
```

Note:

- I would suggest using a `FileOutputStream` wrapped in an `OutputStreamWriter` instead of using `FileWriter`, as you can't specify an encoding with `FileWriter`
- Use a `try`/`finally` block (or try-with-resources in Java 7) so that you always close the writer even if there's an exception.

Comment: What If I want to create a new directory and want to specify the path of this new directory as the location where my file would be stored.?

Comment: @Hukamanata: Then you use `directory.mkdirs()` between the first and second lines...

Comment: Thanks a lot for both your answers..It is working in the desired manner.

Answer (score 0):

To create a file in a specific directory, you need to specify it in the file name.

Otherwise it will use the current working directory which is likely to be where the program was started from.

BTW: Unless you are using Java 1.4 or older, you can use StringBuilder instead of StringBuffer, although in this case PrintWriter would be even better.